# sqlite on dreamhost via flask/JSON - getting 404s

Tags: python, json, sqlite, flask, dreamhost

I've got a flask app that queries a sqlite database and returns a list to html via jsonify. It works fine on localhost, but I've uploaded to dreamhost and am getting 404s for the jsonified lists. I can't tell whether it is an issue with flask communicating with my sqlite database, flask, or with json.

Here is the flask app:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3 as sqlite
import json
from flask import Flask, g, jsonify, make_response, render_template

DEBUG = True
DATABASE = './whdt_combined.db'

#setup flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

##########################
### DATABASE STUFF #######
##########################

#connect to the database
def connect_db():
    rv = sqlite.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = dict_factory
    return rv

#function for making rows nice
def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

#open new db connection if ones hasn't been opened
def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

#when application stops, close db connection
@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

#easy function to nicely query the db
def query_db(query, args=(), one    =False):
    cur  = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv

##########################
### APPLICATION ##########
##########################

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<data1>/<data2>/<region>/<year>/1/')
def datafunction1(data1, data2, region, year):
data = []
for row in query_db('SELECT ccode, country, year, region, ' + data1 + ' FROM whdt WHERE year = ' + year + ' AND region = "' + region + '" AND ' + data1 + ' != "" AND ' + data1 + ' > 0 AND ' + data1 + ' < 100 ORDER BY ' + data1 + ' DESC'):
    countrywhole = {
        'country' :row['country'],      
        'ccode':row['ccode'],
        'year':row['year'],
        'region':row['region'],
        data1:row[data1]
    }
    data.append(countrywhole)
return jsonify( { 'data': data } )    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here is my folder setup:

```
/home/user/mydomain.com/myapp/whdt_combined.db
/home/user/mydomain.com/myapp/myapp.py
/home/user/mydomain.com/myapp/__init__.py
/home/user/mydomain.com/myapp/templates/index.html
/home/user/mydomain.com/myapp/static/a couple of css and js files
```

Flask is not having trouble rendering index.html. Part of the issue is I don't know how to debug through dreamhost. I'm fairly new to this stuff so I'm sorry if I am missing something obvious or otherwise clearly don't know what I'm talking about. Please let me know if I should be providing other important information here. And thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your application does not generate 404 errors, so this is a failure to match your route. Check the URLs generated.

Comment: You should learn about SQL parameters ASAP before someone goes Little Bobby Tables on your database; you are wide open to SQL injection attacks here. Read the intro text to the [`sqlite3` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) carefully.

Comment: After some googling I still unfortunately don't know what you mean by failure to match the route. The generated URLs work just fine on localhost? I don't understand why they'd break here.

Comment: Flask would only return a 404 if it couldn't match a configure route, or you explicitly return a 404 (`abort(404)`). Perhaps your `index.html` is not generating correct URLs?

Comment: It's generating the same urls that work on localhost, which is why I thought it might be an issue with flask's connection to the database? eg GET http://mydomain.com/gdp_growth/urban_pct/Latin%20America%20&%20Caribbean/2005/1/ 404 (NOT FOUND) vs 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2014 20:47:46] "GET /gdp_growth/urban_pct/Latin%20America%20&%20Caribbean/2005/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200